# Using GCP secret manager with cloud build and deply using cloud deploy

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to find the best way to provide secrets to kubernetes pod and use the cloud build and deploy from GCP

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  #args: ['build', '.', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/test-clouddeploy-image:${COMMIT_SHA}', '-f', 'Dockerfile.app']
  #args: ['build', '-f', 'Dockerfile.app', '-t', 'us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/backend/app', '.']
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
    - -c
    - |
        docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/test-clouddeploy-image:${COMMIT_SHA} -f Dockerfile.app --build-arg MONGO_URI=$$MONGO_URI .
  secretEnv: ['MONGO_URI']
```

## Push the container image

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/test-clouddeploy-image:${COMMIT_SHA}']
```

## Create release in Google Cloud Deploy

```
- name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args:
    [
      "deploy", "releases", "create", "release-${SHORT_SHA}",
      "--delivery-pipeline", "test-backend",
      "--region", "us-west1",
      "--annotations", "commitId=${REVISION_ID}",
      "--images", "test-clouddeploy-image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/test-clouddeploy-image:${COMMIT_SHA}"
    ]

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/MONGO_URI/versions/latest
    env: 'MONGO_URI'
```

Skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v3alpha1
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - deployment.yaml
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: clouddeploy-deployment
  labels:
    app: project-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: project-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: project-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: project-test
        image: test-clouddeploy-image
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 512Mi
        autoscaling:
          enabled: true
          minReplicas: 1
          maxReplicas: 2
          targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8000
            protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: clouddeploy-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: project-test
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask the question because you use an anti-pattern. If you solve it, you solve your issue

Let me explain. A container is a simple box. It's not hardened, it's not secure. Putting a secret (I don't know why the MongoDB URI is a secret, but it's a generic comment) in a container, it's like putting it in plain text.

Therefore, the secret must not be in the container, but loaded dynamically in the runtime environment.

Therefore, don't put the MONGO_URI in the container, but load it at runtime from your code or from the environment. You have documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/using-other-products#google-kubernetes-engine).